# Notifications according to the current locale

Tags: android, gps, google-maps-android-api-2, android-notifications

What method can i use to create notifications that are triggered upon reaching a certain place?

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make a service and monitor the geolocation. See the link below on how to monitor geolocation:

http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html

and Services:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html